# What does 2 in square bracket of function f[x_][2]?

Tags: function-construction, syntax

There is a function which looks like `f[x_][2]:=` . What does 2 in square bracket mean?

Comment: It's a nested function where `2` is one of the arguments. One could also write a function like `f[x_][y_] := {x, y}`, for instance.

Comment: `Array[f[x_], 5]`

Comment: You may also find [this](https://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node92.html) and [this](https://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node175.html) sections of my book useful. There I have briefly discussed such functions. Technically such definitions are called `SubValues`, and you may search for this term on this site and elsewhere, to find more information on these.